# Why is Vim able to defeat my file permissions? OS X

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, file-permissions

I'm curious about why Vim seems to be able to override my file permissions even when I'm logged in as a non-admin user.

```
dq-donahue:perm_prac fartknocker$ login root
Password:

dq-donahue:~ root# cd /Users/fartknocker/perm_prac/
dq-donahue:perm_prac root# touch derp
dq-donahue:perm_prac root# ls -l

-rw-r--r--  1 root         staff   0 Nov 23 13:39 derp

dq-donahue:perm_prac root# logout
dq-donahue:perm_prac fartknocker$ vim derp
```

… here I add to the file with vim and use wq! to override the read only permission for the
fartknocker account …

```
dq-donahue:perm_prac fartknocker$ ls -l

-rw-r--r--  1 fartknocker  staff  13 Nov 23 13:39 derp
```

What gives? Why is Vim able to achieve this? Fartknocker is an os x "standard" account. Also, sorry about the funny account name. :) Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it works because you own your home dir and have permissions to make ownership changes in it, and so vim does an effective "chown" by moving the files around and writing a new one in the background first so you can write it. It's not an actual chown as pointed out. You can also see [another answer to this here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58880/how-does-vim-steal-root-owned-files)

IME, 99% of problems on *nix are path and permissions. here, it's permissions. You have permissions on the parent directory to unlink the file and make another file.

If you have permissions on the directory that you're trying to change the file , you will be able to do it. Try this as root:

```
mkdir foo
chmod 777 foo
touch foo/bar.txt
```

and you'll be able to edit and force write the file.

However (as in /tmp), the sticky bit stops you unlinking the file as pointed out by @Keith Thompson in the thread below. So to extend the example above, you could do the following as root:

```
touch foo/bar2.txt
chmod a+wt foo   # this sets the sticky bit
```

now you won't be able to force write the bar2.txt file.

Comment: Thanks! That was driving me crazy.

Comment: Vim can't `chown` the file any more than it can write to it.

Comment: @looch: This answer is incorrect; `vim` cannot `chown` a file unless it's running as root (and won't try even if it is). The other answer is correct. vim doesn't override the permissions on the file.

Comment: It didn't change the ownership of the file. It created a *new* file, which happens to have the same name. The old file is deleted.

Comment: ok, it's the same effect though. updated my answer to be more illustrutive of the actual process. however, moving a file and then making a new one based on the same name with your user is the same effect as chowning it, even if that's not the command it did.

Comment: @KeithThompson do you mind removing the down vote now i've updated my answer and linked another explanation?

Comment: What does that last sentence refer to? Why does it matter whether the file is in `/tmp` or elsewhere?

Comment: did you try it? it doesn't work in /tmp. i was showing it was about ownership of the parent dir

Comment: It doesn't work in /tmp because it has the [sticky bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sticky.8.html) set. It's not so much because the user is not the owner. For a directory: a) not owned by the user, b) where the user has write permission, and c) which doesn't have the sticky bit set, Vim would still be able to unlink the original and create a new file.

Comment: you're right, my explanation wasn't complete enough and i've learnt something about the subtlety of the sticky bit, so i've re-edited my answer again to reflect your comments.

Answer (score 2):

In my testing, Vim unlinks the original file (which requires write permission on the containing directory, not the file itself). Then it writes a new file. This can be determined by examining the file's inode using `ls -li` or `stat`.

```
$ sudo touch foo
$ ls -li foo
57457973 -rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  0 Nov 23 13:07 foo
$ vi foo
... modify file and write with :wq! ...
$ ls -li foo
57457990 -rw-r--r--  1 ken  staff  15 Nov 23 13:07 foo
```

The inode has changed.